# Converting Web Site Project to Web Application Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, vs-web-application-project

I recently changed my project from a Website Project to a Web Application project so I could use build events.

I'm having all sorts of problems now trying to develop.

When I build the project and reload it in the web browser, it hardly ever loads the right version (sometimes it does).

Like if I make a simple update to some text, it will load the last page, like it's using a cached version of the page or something.

Also when I try to debug, it will never hit the breakpoints.  I'm not sure what I need to change to fix this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? The chances are the pages are being cached. With most browsers you can do Ctrl + F5 to force a reload of the cached files.

In Internet Explorer, you can change the option for Temporary Internet Files to 'Every time I visit the webpage', but be aware that this affects all sites you visit.

[image: IE Settings]

If you are talking about changes to binaries, you might need to do an iisreset. If you are still having issues, try deleting ASP.NET temp files.